# KMeans parallel processing failing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, k-means, gil

I'm running k-means on a big data set.  I set it up like this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=500, max_iter = 1, n_init=1, 
  init = 'random', precompute_distances = 0, n_jobs = -2)

# The following line computes the fit on a matrix "mat"
km.fit(mat)
```

My machine has 8 cores.  The documentation says "for n_jobs = -2, all CPUs but one are used."  I can see that there several extra Python processes running while `km.fit` is executing, but only one CPU gets used.

Does this sound like a [GIL issue](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)?  If so, is there any way to get all CPU's to work?  (It seems like there must be ... otherwise what is the point of the `n_jobs` argument).

I'm guessing I'm missing something basic and someone can either confirm my fear or get me back on track; if it's actually more involved, I'll turn to setting up a working example.

**Update 1.**  For simplicity, I switched `n_jobs` to be positive 2.  Here is what's going on with my system during execution:

[image]

Actually I'm not the only user on the machine, but

```
free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'
```

indicates that 88% of RAM is free (confusing to me, since the RAM usage looks like at least 27% on the screenshot above).

**Update 2.**  I updated `sklearn` version to 0.15.2, and nothing changed in the `top` output reported above.  Experimenting with different values of `n_jobs` similarly gives no improvement.

Comment: Not a GIL issue, because `KMeans` will spawn processes, not threads. How much data are you feeding in? Do you have enough memory? Which scikit-learn version? Did you try `n_jobs=-1` or `n_jobs=2` (just to verify)?

Comment: See the update.  The data is about 3 gigs csv read in via pandas -> numpy, while machine RAM is 24 gigs; I can't see how memory is the issue.  Current update uses `n_jobs = 2`.

Comment: Version:  scikit-learn==0.14.1

Comment: That's an old version. K-means was optimized a lot in 0.15.

Comment: @larsmans the version is updated, still no luck.

Comment: How big is "big data set" in your case? How long does it take?

Comment: By "big" I mean big enough that I'm pretty sure the times I observe are dominated by the computations I'm interested rather than overhead.  I'm using about 10 million rows and 20 variables; this runs in about 200 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

The parallelism for KMeans is just running multiple initializations in parallel. As you set n_init=1, there is only one initialization and nothing to parallelize over. The docstring for n_jobs seems wrong at the moment. I'm not sure what happened there.

Comment: Fixed it (should be on the website soonish).

Comment: Interesting, I had not thought of that possibility.  That is disappointing, if true, because even within a single initialization, I expect that there is much to parallelize over.  There are a huge number of distance computations between each of the 500 (in my case) initial centers and all the rest of the points.

Comment: These are all done via BLAS, and if your BLAS is multicore, they will be parallelized.